# How to include environment variable in bash line CURL?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

Trying to get Transmission to notify when download complete.

This works:

```
curl -u <my-api-token>: \
  -X POST https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data-binary '{"type": "note", "title": "$TR_TORRENT_NAME", \
  "body": "$TR_TORRENT_NAME completed."}'
```

... except it pushes `$TR_TORRENT_NAME` and not the actual contents of that variable.

Do I need to escape some quote or something?

Comment: save 10 seconds and just use single quote again in variable `' "$TR_TORRENT_NAME completed" '`

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Inside single-quotes, the shell expands nothing.  Place them inside double-quotes instead:

```
curl -u <my-api-token>: \
  -X POST https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data-binary '{"type": "note", "title": "'"$TR_TORRENT_NAME"'", \
  "body": "'"$TR_TORRENT_NAME completed"'."}'
```

Let's examine how this works by looking at:

```
$ TR_TORRENT_NAME=MyTorrent
$ echo '{"type": "note", "title": "'"$TR_TORRENT_NAME"'", "body": "'"$TR_TORRENT_NAME completed"'."}'
{"type": "note", "title": "MyTorrent", "body": "MyTorrent completed."}
```

When the shell variable appears, it is always inside double-quotes. Consequently, it is properly expanded.

Quoting like this is a bit subtle.  We have single-quoted strings that contain double-quotes as characters and are next to double-quoted strings.  To understand this better, let's take this fragment as a an example:

```
 "'"$TR_TORRENT_NAME"'"
```

Taking each character in turn:

1. `"` is a literal double-quote character that is inside of a single-quoted string. (For brevity, the beginning of this string is not shown in this fragment.)
2. `'` closes a single-quoted string.
3. `"` opens a double-quoted string.
4. `$TR_TORRENT_NAME` is a shell variable that is expanded inside double-quotes.
5. `"` closes the double-quoted string.
6. `'` opens a new single-quoted string.
7. `"` places a double-quote character inside the single-quoted string.

Comment: Do you need steps 3 and 5?

Comment: @davidfrancis If one omits steps 3 and 5, then step 4 is subject to _word splitting_ and _pathname expansion_ and either one could cause all manor of trouble.  Unless one explicitly wants _word splitting_ and _pathname expansion_, a shell variable should always be inside double-quotes.

Comment: Thanks for that, can you give a quick example please? It worked in my own example, which is why I asked, but there were no spaces or anything else complex in there

Comment: @davidfrancis Try `TR_TORRENT_NAME="A * B"` and see what happens.

Comment: I'm always surprised every time I am reminded that bash just concatenates strings without any operator.

Answer (score 7):

To include an environment variable in a bash line curl without quotes around the variable content, this worked for me:

```
--header 'PRIVATE-TOKEN: '"$PRIVATE_TOKEN"''
```

Or using the scenario that was first described without quotes around the body field:

```
curl -u <my-api-token>: \
  -X POST https://api.pushbullet.com/v2/pushes \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data-binary '{"type": "note", "title": "'"$TR_TORRENT_NAME"'", \
  "body": '"$TR_TORRENT_NAME completed"'.}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Put quotes at the end and double quotes around the environment variable is the easiest way:

1. Initialize and export the variable-

   ```
    export TR_TORRENT_NAME="foo"
   ```
2. Import the variable-

   ```
    echo  "{"type": "note", "title": ""$TR_TORRENT_NAME"", "body": ""$TR_TORRENT_NAME"" "completed."}"
   ```
3. The response would look like-

   ```
    {type: note, title: foo, body: foo completed.}
   ```

Comment: The output is not a valid json. See John1024's answer above